# Deserialize JSON array into List

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to deserialize a json object.  It works fine to a certain point. I have an Area object, which contains an array of Zone objects.

```
{
  "Area":{
    "id": "0",
    "type": "area",
    "size": {
      "x": 4.5,
      "y": 4.5,
      "z": 4.5
    },
    "position": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "z": 0
    },
    "rotation": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "z": 0
    },
    "zones": [
      {
        "id": "001",
        "type": "zone",
        "size": {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 1,
          "z": 1
        },
        "position": {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 1
        },
        "rotation": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "002",
        "type": "zone",
        "size": {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 1,
          "z": 1
        },
        "position": {
          "x": 3,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 1
        },
        "rotation": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `Area` type deserializes fine, however, I'd like for the zone array to deserialize to a `List<Zone>`.  How can I achieve this?

```
string jsonString = r.ReadToEnd();
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Area area = jss.Deserialize<Area>(jsonString);

public class Area : AirObject3D
{
    public List<Zone> zones;
    public List<TouchPoint> touchPoints;
    public Area()
    {
        this.size.X = 4.5;
        this.size.Z = 4.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to deserialize it to other list? Or to the list that is in class `Area`?

Comment: Just put a property `zones` of type `List<Zone>` into the `Area` type.

Comment: Change the `Area` class's `Zones` property from `Zone[]` to `List<Zone>`?

Comment: @nopeflow, I'd like it to be a child of Area type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set up your contract correctly. In order to deserialize a list, you can just set the property type to `List<Zone>` (you can also deserialize into an array using `Zone[]`).

Your contract could for example look like this:

```
public class Root
{
    public Area Area { get; set; }
}
public class Area
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("size")]
    public Coordinate Size { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("position")]
    public Coordinate Position { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("rotation")]
    public Coordinate Rotation { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("zones")]
    public List<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
}
public class Zone
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("size")]
    public Coordinate Size { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("position")]
    public Coordinate Position { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("rotation")]
    public Coordinate Rotation { get; set; }
}
public class Coordinate
{
    [XmlElement("x")]
    public float X { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("y")]
    public float Y { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("z")]
    public float Z { get; set; }
}
```

Note the use of the [`XmlElementAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) to ensure that the lower-case properties are correctly deserialized into the capitalized C# properties (since properties should be capitalized by convention).

Used like this on your data, it properly fills all the objects:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Root root = jss.Deserialize<Root>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks, if I capitalize in the json, could I lose the XMLElement defs?

Comment: Yeah, if the properties in the JSON match the property names in the class, you can leave it out (as I did in the `Root` class).

Comment: That's great. Thanks poke :-)

Answer (score -6):

your object graph should look like -

```
public class Size
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    public double z { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int z { get; set; }
}

public class Rotation
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int z { get; set; }
}

public class Zone
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Size size { get; set; }
    public Position position { get; set; }
    public Rotation rotation { get; set; }
}

public class Area
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Size size { get; set; }
    public Position position { get; set; }
    public Rotation rotation { get; set; }
    public List<Zone> zones { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Area Area { get; set; }
}

var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("json");
```

Comment: This is a blanket statement and not specific to the OP's question at all.

Comment: more a copy past of json2csharp.com

Comment: The other answer had an explanation.